# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'SalutationName'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Now i am new in MVC ..Please resolve my problems..Thanks is advance

```
**This is MY View**

   @Html.DropDownList("SalutationName", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Titles, "--------------Select-------------", new { id = "R_title" })


**This is My Controller**

  public ActionResult Index()
       {  var list=RoleID();
            IList<salutation> p = list;
            ViewBag.Titles = new SelectList(p.AsEnumerable(), "SalutationID", "SalutationName");
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: What is sign of the RoleID() method? how is defined the 'salutation' class?

Comment: RoleID() is used to getting the list from DB. The list assign to Salutation Ilist

Comment: What is the exact signature? what is the definition of the salutation class?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Html.DropDownList("Salutation",ViewBag.Titles as SelectList,"---select---",new { id = "R_title" })
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@Html.DropDownList("SalutationName",ViewBag.Titles, "--------------Select-------------", new { id = "R_title" })
```

Comment: Hi..i have tried ,but i get an Compilation Error                          Compiler Error Message: CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' has no applicable method named 'DropDownList' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Comment: Just typecast the `ViewBag.Titles` to `(SelectList)ViewBag.Titles` and it'll work - as Syed did it.